# Kendo UI - How to post data from multiple tabs in a tabstrip

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have created a Kendo tabstrip that I am using as a wizard style form. The tabs are all partial views with their own data entry. I have set up the entire tabstrip as a form, but whenever I post data to my database, it only collects from the FIRST partial view.

If I make a different partial view the first one, THAT is the one that posts. Regardless of the view, the data posts from the view in the first position of the `tabstrip`.

Does anyone have any idea how to collect data from multiple tabs beyond the first?
Here is the `tabstrip` and the form begin, let me know what else you need.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "assetRequestForm", role = "form" }))
{
    @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
      .Name("tabstrip")
      .Items(tabstrip =>
      {
          tabstrip.Add().Text("User Information")
              .Selected(true)
              .Content(m => Html.Partial("_tab1", m));

          tabstrip.Add().Text("Transfer Info")
              .Enabled(true)
              .Content(m => Html.Partial("_tab2", m));

          tabstrip.Add().Text("Breckenridge")
              .Enabled(true)
              .Content(m => Html.Partial("_Tab3", m));

          tabstrip.Add().Text("Submit")
              .Enabled(true)
              .Content(m => Html.Partial("_Tab4", m));
      }))
}
```

Comment: If you are using separate models you can just have the user post the data as they move along the wizard.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue, sort of. There is an issue with one of my partial views causing data to not post from it. I haven't figured out exactly what it is yet, but I have made other views work and post data.